# How to support 3dconnexion SpaceMouse in a GLFW C++ application?

Tags: c++, mouseevent, glfw, hid

I would like to add support of a 3dconnexion [SpaceMouse](https://3dconnexion.com/us/spacemouse/) device in a cross-platform (Windows, Linux, Mac) 3D C++ application based on [glfw](https://www.glfw.org/) library.

I downloaded 3DxWare_SDK_v4-0-2_r17624 from the device vendor, and looked at the simplest C++ sample: 3DxTraceNL. Unfortunately, it is really huge: its source code (.cpp+.h+.hpp) weights more than 200Kb, even if we do not add here 100+Kb of `navlib` headers, which is the base of the application. The sample includes tons of code for Camera, Matrices, Transforms, Navigation models and so on, which I already have in my application and do not want to replace just to support new device.

What I basically look for is how to register for and receive SpaceMouse events in glfw framework. The processing of events I will will write by myself. Even if you could suggest a glfw-compatible solution for one particular platform, that would be great.

Answer (score 2):

The solution I found is to use [HIDAPI](https://github.com/libusb/hidapi) to communicate with SpaceMouse device (which is available on Windows, Linux and Mac) instead of 3DxWare_SDK.

One has to create an `std::thread` that will in a loop

1. Enumerate the devices with `hid_enumerate`. `vendor_id` argument is either `0x046d` for classical devices or `0x256f` for wireless devices.
2. If a device is found, connect to it with `hid_open_path`.
3. Periodically read messages from the connected device using `hid_read` or `hid_read_timeout`.
4. As soon as the message is received, notify the application with `glfwPostEmptyEvent()` in case it is waiting in `glfwWaitEvents()`.

In GLFW event processing loop, check that new message is arrived somewhere near `glfwPollEvents()` call.

The messages from SpaceMouse devices are rather simple and contain at most 13 bytes:

1. If the first byte is 3, then this message contains the status of device's buttons in the following bits.
2. If the first byte is 2, then the following 6 bytes contain the torque (rotation) of device's handle.
3. If the first byte is 1, then the following 6 bytes contain the shift (translation) of device's handle. If the message has 13 bytes in length, the the last 6 bytes contain the rotation data.

One can find a similar implementation in open-source [MeshLib](https://github.com/MeshInspector/MeshLib), see `class SpaceMouseHandlerHidapi`.